# Intuition and not the answer behind the rainbow hat puzzle

Tags: recreational-mathematics, intuition, puzzle

Let me first pose the problem:

> The king of some faraway land is bored, so he decides to setup a little game for his own amusement. These are the rules of the game:
>
> 7 prisoners will be seated at a round table. Each prisoner will have a hat placed on their head. Each hat is one of seven possible colors. The prisoners can see everyone else's hat, but they cannot see their own. The prisoners will then write on a piece of paper what they think their hat color is, and hand the paper to the king.
> If any of the prisoners guesses their hat color correctly, they will all go free. Otherwise, they are all executed on the spot.
>
> If the prisoners use the naive strategy of guessing randomly, then they have a survival chance of 66%. Can you think of a strategy such that the prisoners have a 100% chance of survival?

When given this problem, my brain subconsciously pointed towards modular arithmetic and I gave a satisfactory answer that solved the problem. My answer matched the answers given in this Math SE answer: [Rainbow Hats Puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149915/rainbow-hats-puzzle)

A person I was explaining this problem to said that the answer worked in retrospect, but it required a logical leap to arrive at the answer. Introspection revealed that I too took a subconscious shortcut towards modular arithmetic without natural deduction.

My question is this: Is there a way to solve this systematically without a logic leap and with natural deduction or inferences. Understanding the modular arithmetic answer is easy in retrospect, but explaining how one might arrive at the solution is much harder.

Comment: I think I didn't understand the problem correcty. If the prisioner saw the colors of the others 6 prisioners hats, then he'll automatically know his hat color, since there are only 7 hats colors avaible.

Comment: @meuestudo I think there may be several hats available per colour.

Comment: Ah there is a pool of 7 colors which everyone knows before hand. Colors can be repeated. So you could all be wearing hats of the same color

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: For any winning strategy, there exists a function $f$ which, given a hat assignment, tells us the name of a prisoner who guesses correctly. The domain of $f$ has $7^7$ elements and the codomain has $7$ elements. To ensure that $f(x)=i$ implies prisoner $i$ guesses correctly, prisoner $i$ must always be able to deduce his hat color from the others' by assuming $f(x)=i$. A natural choice of $f$ meeting these requirements is the sum mod 7, and this determines the strategy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't know the problem in this particular form before and just solved it on my own using modular arithmetic. I will tell you my thinking process, hoping it suffices to answer your question.

A prisoner sees six hats and has to make a guess for the colour of their own hat. Of the seven colours possible, they will guess correctly exactly once. That means, a prisoner will call the correct colour for exactly one seventh of the $7^7$, that is $7^6$, possible distributions of hats to prisoners. In total, we get $7^7$ correct guesses from all seven prisoners for $7^7$ cases. That means we cannot waste even a single correct guess. We have to make sure that in each case *exactly* one of the prisoners guesses correctly.

Let $C$ be the set of colours and $P = \{1,\dotsc,7\}$ the set of prisoners. Suppose we already know a solution to the puzzle. Since for each hat distribution $c \in C^7$ there is a correct call from exactly one prisoner, we can form the function $f \colon C^7 \to P$, where $f(c) = p$ if $p$ is the one to guess correctly on hat distribution $c$. This function has an interesting property: Let $p \in P$ be a prisoner and fix colours $c_q \in C$ for all prisoners $q \neq p$. Then there is exactly one colour $c_p$ such that $f((c_q)_{q \in P}) = p$. This is just the fact that $p$ guesses exactly one colour when they see hats $(c_q)_{q \neq p}$.

This correspondence between solutions of the puzzle and functions goes both ways. Given a function $f$ as above, the prisoners can use the following strategy: If $p \in P$ sees hats $(c_q)_{q \neq p}$, have $p$ guess the unique colour $c_p$ such that $f((c_q)_{q \in P}) = p$. Then on hat distribution $c$, prisoner $f(c)$ guesses correctly.

If we can construct an $f$ as above, we are done. The special property it has to fulfill is a bit weird, though. It becomes more managable if we replace it by something stronger. Instead of only expecting a unique $c_p$ such that $f((c_q)_{q \in P}) = p$, we can demand a unique $c_p$ such that $f((c_q)_{q \in P}) = p'$ for *all* $p' \in P$, not just $p' = p$. Another way to phrase this: After fixing colours $c_q$ for $q \neq p$, the map $C \to P$ sending the remaining colour $c_p$ to $f((c_q)_{q \in P})$ is bijective.

We are now looking for a function $C^7 \to P$ that is bijective in each argument when leaving the other six fixed. You wanted to use modular arithmetic, so identify both $C$ and $P$ with $\mathbb{Z} / (7)$. Then we need a map $(\mathbb{Z} / (7))^7 \to \mathbb{Z} / (7)$ bijective in each argument. Just adding up all the seven arguments should work.

Note: I did not formalize the correspondence between solutions and functions $f$ before writing this down. I thought about what was needed to reconstruct a valid strategy from $f$. At first I noted that $f$ being in bijective in each argument works. I figured out the exact condition on $f$ after I had the solution already.

Comment: This was good! I enjoy the formalism. I didn't formalize my solution and writing it in a formal way makes it more easy to get to the solution. Thank you :) If I were to extract a kernel of truth from this problem that is transferrable to add to ones toolbox, what would that be?

Comment: Ask yourself: What exactly am I looking for? What kind of mathematical object gives rise to a solution? How can I construct such an object?