# Modified hat problem seems hard

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

I found the following problem on instagram:

> Seven prisoners are given the chance to be set free tomorrow. An
> executioner will put a hat on each prisoner's head. Each hat can be
> one of the seven colors of the rainbow and the hat colors are assigned
> completely at the executioner's discretion. Every prisoner can see the
> hat colors of the other six prisoners, but not his own. They cannot
> communicate with others in any form, or else they are immediately
> executed. Then each prisoner writes down his guess of his own hat
> color. If at least one prisoner correctly guesses the color of his
> hat, they all will be set free immediately; otherwise they will be
> executed. They are given the night to come up with a strategy. Is
> there a strategy that they can guarantee that they will be set free?

Now, generalizing this for n people and n hats, the usual solution involves coding each color with a number in Z/nZ and for the ith person to calculate what it's hat color should be if the sum of all colors was equal to i. More information here: ([Rainbow Hats Puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149915/rainbow-hats-puzzle)).

I, however, didn't really like this solution because each person is using the information of its own personhood (it's i value) as well as what they can see in the circle. In other words, the "strategy" is a function of each color the person is seeing as well as of which person it is: f(c1,...,c_(n-1) , i).

I was wondering if, by not allowing the last variable it is still possible to solve it (meaning the strategy must not differentiate each individual but depend only on the colors that are seen). I think it isn't and managed to prove by hand that n = 2 and n = 3 are impossible.

My first try to attack this problem so far has been to consider some special cases to gain information about f and try to achieve a contradiction. For example, it's easy to see that f(c,c,...,c) = c ( if all the colors a person sees are equal, the strategy must involve them saying that color ).
My second try was a counting argument but i don't really know combinatorics so my ideas were limited.

Anyone has any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @BrianTung this is the usual solution, but you see how the strategy is a function of k ( the prisoner number)?  I was wondering if we can find a strategy which is independent of k and dependent only on the color that are seen

Comment: Ahh OK. I don't see how similar configurations can be sufficiently distinguished without using prisoner identity, though. Also, given that they are already permitted to agree on a strategy beforehand, on what basis are we denying them the right to choose an identity amongst themselves? It seems rather arbitrary (not that that isn't a quality of the problem to begin with!).

Comment: I agree, it doesn't seem like sufficient information, but i also can't prove it isn't. To me the question, when i first read it was mathematically equivalent to: is there a function f which receives n-1 colors and returns another color s.t.  for any c1,...,cn; one of f(c1,...,cn-1), f(c2,...,cn) ,... is equal to the removed color? Since i was seeing the question this way, the addition of k as an argument sounded weird, so i wondered about the question.

Comment: Are you assuming they hear each other's answers, in turn? Or do they give them all at once and/or secretly?

Comment: @BrianTung just as in the original problem, they say their answers secretly.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a probabilistic argument.

Suppose the executioner decides to allocate the hat colours uniformly at random with replacement, i.e. with $n^n$ equally likely possible allocations.

Then the probability an individual prisoner's guess as to their own colour has probability $\frac1n$ of being correct, and the expected number of correct guesses is $1$.

If there is a non-zero probability that two or more guesses are correct then there must also be a non-zero probability that no guesses are correct, which prevents the guarantee.

So no prisoner can adopt a strategy which has any randomness in response to the colours seen.

Nor can two prisoners adopt identical strategies, since there is a non-zero probability that they both see the same pattern of colours on others.

So any overall strategy providing the guarantee must require distinct individual response strategies for different prisoners, so each response depends on the individual answering.  The linked answer to this question is an example of such distinct strategies and it works, though there may be other possibilities that also work.

Comment: If n is a prime number, the only cases where more than one person in the circle would see the same colors would be if all colors were identical, in which case we just demand the strategy to pick that color. This seems to contradict what you said, since there'd be 0 chance for n prime (apart from the case i mentioned) of people seeing the same colors. Does this invalidate your argument? I dont really know

Comment: @victormd: if $n=3$ and the colours (selected say from the three of red and yellow and green) actually used are two red and one yellow, then both of the two people with red on their own heads will each see one red and one yellow on the others' heads.  Achieving the guarantee then needs them to make different guesses for what colour is on their own heads.

Comment: They'll be seeing the same colors but in different order, though. One will use the strategy f(Yellow, Red) while the other will use f(Red, Yellow)

Comment: @victormd I am not sure that is a difference, but instead try another example with $n=2$:  if the two people do not react differently to each other when they see the other hat is red (or when they see the other hat is yellow) then you will not meet the guarantee

Answer (score 3):

If the prisoners can't use any numerical identification of themselves in choosing their strategy, then each prisoner's choice can only depend on the [*multiset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of colours that he or she sees.  In other words, if $\ f\ $ is the function representing the prisoners' choices, then $\ f\big(c_1,c_2,\dots, c_{n-1}\big)=$$\,f\big(d_1,d_2,\dots,d_{n-1}\big)\ $ whenever $\ \big\{c_1,c_2,\dots, c_{n-1}\big\}\ $ and $\ \big\{d_1,d_2,\dots,d_{n-1}\}\ $ are equal *as multisets.* For such a function to guarantee the prisoners' freedom it must satisfy the following condition:

> For every multiset $\ S\ $ of cardinality $\ n\ ,$ of the available colours, there exists at least one $\ c\in S\ $ such that $$ f(S\setminus {c})=c \label{e1}\tag{1}$$

Call such a function a *survival function*.

Suppose $\ f\ $ is a survival function. As you've already deduced, it must satisfy
$$
f\big(\big\{c^{n-1}\big\}\big)=c\ .
$$
Now if the prisoners adopt $\ f\ $ for their strategy, $\ n-1\ $ of them are assigned the same colour, $\ c\ ,$ and the remaining one assigned the colour $\ d\ne c\ ,$ then the colour chosen by this latter prisoner will be $\ f\big(\big\{c^{n-1},d\big\}\setminus\{d\}\big)=$$\,f\big(\big\{c^{n-1}\big\}\big)=$$\,c\ ,$ while all the other prisoners, with $ c$-coloured hats, will choose the same colour $\ f\big(\big\{c^{n-1},d\big\}\setminus\{c\}\big)=$$\,f\big(\big\{c^{n-2},d\big\}\big)\ .$ Since the prisoner with the $\ d$-coloured hat will have nominated the wrong colour, $\ c\ ,$ for his or her hat, then for $\ f\ $ to be a survival function, we must have $\ f\big(\big\{c^{n-2},d\big\}\big)=$$\,c\ .$ By repeating this argument with successively larger multisets $\ D\ $ with $\ c\not\in D\ ,$ we can show by induction that for any such non-empty multiset of cardinality $\ r\le n-3\ $, $\ f\big(\big\{c^{n-r-1}\}\cup D\big)=$$\,c\ .$ However, for $\ n\ge5\ $ this would require both $\ f\big(\big\{c^2,d^{n-3}\big\}\big)=$$\,c\ $ and $\ f\big(\big\{c^2,d^{n-3}\big\}\big)=$$\,d\ $ for any pair of colours $\ c,d\ $ with $\ c\ne d\ ,$ which is clearly impossible. Thus, there doesn't exist a survival function for $\ n\ge5\ .$  For $\ n=4\ $ it would require $\ f\big(\big\{c^2,d^2\}\setminus\{d\}\big)=c\ $ and $\ f\big(\big\{c^2,d^2\big\}\setminus\{c\}\big)=d\ ,$ so $\ f\ $ would fail the condition (\ref{e1}) for the multiset $\ S=\big\{c^2,d^2\big\}\ $ and therefore not be a survival function. Thus, there doesn't exist a survival function for $\ n=4\ $ either.

Since you've already proved that there's no survival function for $\ n=2\ $ and $\ n=3\ ,$ I haven't bothered trying to extend the above argument to cover those cases.

**Analysis of Alternative Interpretation**

$\def\ed{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
From your comment below, it appears that I've misunderstood what you're asking for.  As I now understand it, you want to allow the prisoners to use a method in which each of them can assign $\ n-1\ $ indices to the colours they see in such a way that every prisoner who sees the same number, say $\ q\ $, of any given colour assigns the *same* set of $\ q\ $ indices to that colour, and those $\ q\ $ prisoners who see only $\ q-1\ $ occurrences of that colour each assign a *different subset* of cardinality $\ q-1\ $ of that *same* set of $\ q\ $ indices to that colour.  If that understanding is correct, then I think you need to be rather more careful in specifying the restrictions on how the prisoners can actually implement the method.  Otherwise it's easy to devise ways in which they can smuggle the standard solution into their implementation.

Suppose, for instance, the prisoners decide that they'll gather in a circle, assign the index $\ 1\ $ to the prisoner nearest the executioner (or some other landmark in the room), the index $\ 2\ $ to the prisoner on prisoner $\ 1$'s left, the index $\ n\ $ to the prisoner on prisoner $\ 1$'s right, and so on around the circle.  They will all then have constructed the *same* bijection between the prisoners and the set of indices $\ \{1,2,\dots,n\}\ ,$ and can therefore use it to implement the standard solution.

In one of your comments above, you appear to be suggesting that a survival function ought to be defined as follows:

> Let $\ C\ $ be the set of colours.  A *survival function* is a function $\ f:C^{n-1}\rightarrow C\ $ such that for every $\ c\in C^n\ $ there exists $ i\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}\ $ such that $$ f\big(c^{<i>}\big)=c_i\ ,\tag{2}\label{e2}$$where$$c^{<i>}_j=\cases{c_j&if $\ j\le i$\\c_{j+1}&if $\ j\ge i+1$}$$

It's possible to adapt the argument used above to show that a survival function of this type can't exist either.  Actually, even if such a function did exist, it seemed to me than any method I could think of for the prisoners to use it to effect an escape could be adapted to allow them to implement the standard solution.  Since any conclusion whatever can be validly drawn from a provably false premise, however, it's not clear whether this observation really is true, or means very much, even if it is.

In the following argument I'll use the notation $\ c_1^{r_1}c_2^{r_2}\dots c_k^{r_k}\ $ to represent an $\ n$-tuple $\left(\text{if $\ \sum_\limits{j=1}^kr_k=n\ $}\right)$ or $\ (n-1)$-tuple $\left(\text{if $\ \sum_\limits{j=1}^kr_k=n-1\ $}\right)$ of colours according to the following definition
$$
\big[c_1^{r_1}c_2^{r_2}\dots c_k^{r_k}\big]_i\ed\cases{c_1&if $\ i\le r_1$\\
 c_j&if $\ \sum_\limits{\ell=1}^{j-1}r_\ell<i\le\sum_\limits{\ell=1}^jr_\ell$
\\
c_k&if $\ \sum_\limits{\ell=1}^{k-1}r_\ell<i\ .$}
$$

Suppose now that $\ f\ $ is survival function in this second sense.  Then, again, as you've already concluded,
$$
f\big(c^{n-1}\big)=c\ .
$$
Now, if $\ b\ne c\ $ then
\begin{align}
f\big(\big(bc^{n-1}\big)^{<1>}\big)&=f\big(\big(c^{n-1}b\big)^{<n>}\big)\\
&=f\big(c^{n-1}\big)\\
&=c\hspace{4em}\text{ from above}\\
&\ne b\\
&=\big[bc^{n-1}\big]_1\\
&=\big[c^{n-1}b\big]_n\ .
\end{align}
Thus, since $\ f\big(\big(bc^{n-1}\big)^{<1>}\big)\ne\big[bc^{n-1}\big]_1 \ ,$ then for condition $(\ref{e2})$ to hold  there must be $\ j\in\{2,3,\dots,n\}\ $ such that
\begin{align}
f\big(\big(bc^{n-1}\big)^{<j>}\big)&=\big[bc^{n-1}\big]_j\\
&=c\ ,
\end{align}
and since $\ \big(bc^{n-1}\big)^{<j>}=bc^{n-2}\ $ for all $\ j\in\{2,3,\dots,n\}\ ,$ it follows that $\ f\big(bc^{n-2}\big)=c\ .$ Likewise, since
$\ f\big(\big(c^{n-1}b\big)^{<n>}\big)\ne$$\,\big[c^{n-1}b\big]_n\ ,$ then there must be $\ j\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}\ ,$ such that $\ f\big(\big(c^{n-1}b\big)^{<j>}\big)=\big[c^{n-1}b\big]_j=c\ ,$ and therefore $\ f\big(c^{n-2}b\big)=c\ .$

Now suppose that $\ 1\le s\le n-3\ ,$ and $\ f\big(b^rc^{n-1-r}\big)=c\ $ for all $\ r\le s\ .$ Then $\ f\big(\big(b^{s+1}c^{n-s-1}\big)^{<j>}\big)=f\big(b^sc^{n-s-1}\big)=c$$\,\ne \big(b^{s+1}c^{n-s-1}\big)_j\ $ for any $\ j\in\{1,2,\dots,s+1\}\ .$ Therefore, for (\ref{e2}) to hold, there must exist $\ j\in\{s+2,\dots,n\}\ $ such that $\ f\big(\big(b^{s+1}c^{n-s-1}\big)^{<j>}\big)=f\big(b^{s+1}c^{n-s-2}\big)=$$\,\big(b^{s+1}c^{n-s-1}\big)_j$$\,=c\ .$ It follows by induction that $\ f\big(b^sc^{n-1-s}\big)=c\ $ for all $\ s\in$$\,\{1,2,\dots,n-2\}\ .$ Likewise, we can apply the same argument to the $\ (n-1)$-tuples of the form $\ c^{n-1-s}b^s\ $ to conclude that $\ f\big(c^{n-1-s}b^s\big)=c\ $ for all $\ s\in$$\,\{1,2,\dots,n-2\}\ .$

The same arguments can obviously also be applied with the colours $\ b\ $ and $\ c\ $ swapped to obtain
\begin{align}
f\big(c^sb^{n-1-s}\big)&=b\hspace{4em}\text{and}\\
f\big(b^{n-1-s}c^s\big)&=b\
\end{align}
for all $\ s\in$$\,\{1,2,\dots,n-2\}\ .$  But this now produces a contradiction for any $\ n\ge3\ ,$ because we require both
\begin{align}
f\big(bc^{n-2}\big)&=c\hspace{4em}\text{and}\\
f\big(bc^{n-2}\big)&=b\ .
\end{align}

Comment: I appreciate your answer, indeed i had thought about restricting f to only sets and was able to arrive at an easier contradiction, but it hadn't occured to me to consider multisets. Still, maybe the prisoners could use the position in which they see the colors as information ( person to my left is red, person 2 steps to my left is yellow, ... ). In this way, we truly must consider f in its full generality, with n-1 independent arguments f(c1,...,cn-1). Can you think of any arguments for that case? Either way, you deserve the upvote

Comment: What seems so hard about f in its full generality is that it seems we can't use any kind of symmetry apart from trivial ones to restrict f.i I think the only way to discard this possibility is with some sort of counting argument maybe